Populate Date Columns from a cell containing list of dates
This is my current dataframe:



Name
Absences
9/1
9/2
9/3
9/4
9/5
9/6




Student1
9/1,9/3,9/4,9/5
0
0
0
0
0
0


Student2
9/1,9/2,9/6
0
0
0
0
0
0


Student3
9/1,9/2,9/3
0
0
0
0
0
0


Student4
9/2
0
0
0
0
0
0



I want to populate the date columns with a 1 if they appear in the Absences column. Unfortunately this is how the data is formatted. I created the date columns, so if you have a slightly different idea please let me know. I am only give 'Name' and 'Absences'.
Desired end result:



Name
Absences
9/1
9/2
9/3
9/4
9/5
9/6




Student1
9/1,9/3,9/4,9/5
1
0
1
1
1
0


Student2
9/1,9/2,9/6
1
1
0
0
0
1


Student3
9/1,9/2,9/3
1
1
1
0
0
0


Student4
9/2
0
1
0
0
0
0



I feel like this can be achieved with apply and a custom function. My two ideas have been to iterate thru the list and populate the corresponding column, or to iterate through the columns and if its in the absences list, then populate with 1. Not succeeding in either

You can use .str.get_dummies():
df['Absences'].str.get_dummies(',')

   9/1  9/2  9/3  9/4  9/5  9/6
0    1    0    1    1    1    0
1    1    1    0    0    0    1
2    1    1    1    0    0    0
3    0    1    0    0    0    0


code you should use create a function that update every row and then use apply it in dataframe
def update_absences(row):
    dates = row['Absences'].split(',')
    for date in dates:
        row[date] = 1
    return row

df = df.apply(update_absences, axis=1)

complete code
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Student1', 'Student2', 'Student3', 'Student4'],
    'Absences': ['9/1,9/3,9/4,9/5', '9/1,9/2,9/6', '9/1,9/2,9/3', '9/2'],
    '9/1': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    '9/2': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    '9/3': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    '9/4': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    '9/5': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    '9/6': [0, 0, 0, 0]
})

# Function to update the data based on the Absences column
def update_absences(row):
    dates = row['Absences'].split(',')
    for date in dates:
        row[date] = 1
    return row

# Apply the  function to each row 
df = df.apply(update_absences, axis=1)

print(df)


"Functions that mutate the passed object can produce unexpected behavior or errors and are not supported." - docs for Series.apply().

It did provide me with result
